# How to convert Xtend code to Xtend templates

Tags: eclipse, templates, xtext, xtend

I have a code written in Xtend, where I am not using templates but I am just printing things out. However, I learned that one the most powerful things about Xtend is that it is template based. Therefore, now I want to write it in Xtend. Is there any simple way to do it (don't really think there is one but the code is quite long so thought I would give it a try asking).
Second, if I have the following:

```
def method(){
method1()
method2()
method3()
...
}
```

In Xtend should I write

```
def method(){
'''
 «method1()»
 «method2()»
 «method3()»
...
'''
}
```

Or can I also write

```
def method(){
'''
 «method1()
 method2()
 method3()»
...
'''
}
```

So to use the terminal only once if I don't have to actually print anything.
Any other tips that would facilitate converting the code according to the Xtend templates are welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: i am not sure if i can follow you. the result of a template expression in Xtend is CharSequence that you can print. So only the variant with separate methods calls makes sense if you check the resulting string. but maybe i got wrong what you want to achieve

Comment: Regarding " but the code is quite long so thought I would give it a try asking": Perhaps the builtin Java-to-Xtend Converter(s) might help you.